# How to get manual for android fp-08 tablet SDK

Tags: android-biometric

I have recently acquired an android tablet device, (model FP-08) with built in bio-metric authentication capabilities, the device comes with a demo apk with capture and enroll capabilities. If any one here knows the device and SDK, does it's documentation exist and could you show me where to get it?

Comment: Contact the manufacturer